Product of two residue classes
For $(1+8ℤ)^2:=\{ ab:a\in 1+8ℤ,b\in1+8ℤ\}$ we clearly have $(1+8ℤ)^2=1+8ℤ$.
similarly, I wonder

Can $(3+8ℤ)^2:=\{ ab:a\in 3+8ℤ,b\in3+8ℤ\}$ be written into a union of finitely many residue classes?

Assume $(3+8ℤ)^2$ can be written as a union of a finite number of residue classes.
Take the least common multiple of these modulus, denoted as $m$.
Therefore, $(3+8ℤ)^2$ is a union of a finite number of residue classes modulo $m$.
Note that $(3+8ℤ)^2\subset 9+8ℤ$
implies that $8$ divides $m$, so let's say $m = 8k$.
Observing that $1\in (9+8ℤ)\setminus(3+8ℤ)^2$, we conclude that $k > 1$.
Observing that
$1\in (1+16ℤ)\setminus(3+8ℤ)^2$
$-7\in (9+16ℤ)\setminus(3+8ℤ)^2$
we conclude that $k > 2$.
I don't know what to do next...

$(3+8\mathbb Z)(3+8\mathbb Z)=9+8\mathbb Z=1+8\mathbb Z$, and $17\in1+8\mathbb Z$

@J.W.Tanner $17\notin(3+8Z)(3+8Z)$ since $17=1\times17=-1\times-17$ cannot be written as a product of two numbers in $3+8Z$

I initially misunderstood this question in exactly the same way as you @J.W.Tanner. The fact that $(a + n\mathbb{Z})(b + n\mathbb{Z}) \subseteq (ab + n\mathbb{Z})$ for any $a, b, n \in \mathbb{Z}$ is equivalent to the fact that multiplication is well-defined modulo $n$. But this is asking about equality.

The answer turns out to be no. Suppose for the sake of contradiction that $(3+8\Bbb Z)^2 = \bigcup_{j=1}^J (a_j+q_j\Bbb Z)$, and define $g_j = \gcd(a_j,q_j)$.
Observation 1: Each $g_j>1$. Because if some $g_j = 1$, then there would be (infinitely many) primes in the arithmetic progression $a_j+q_j\Bbb Z$ by Dirichlet's theorem, yet there are no primes in $(3+8\Bbb Z)^2$.
Observation 2: Every element of $(3+8\Bbb Z)^2$ has a nontrivial common factor with $G=g_1\cdots g_J$. This follows immediately from Observation 1 and the hypothesis $(3+8\Bbb Z)^2 = \bigcup_{j=1}^J (a_j+q_j\Bbb Z)$.
Observation 3: There are infinitely many squares of primes in $(3+8\Bbb Z)^2$. This is because there are infinitely many primes in $3+8\Bbb Z$ (again by Dirichlet's theorem).
But Observations 2 and 3 form a contradiction, since there are only finitely many squares of primes that can have a common factor with $G$ (namely the squares of prime factors of $G$).
This proof generalizes to any $(b+n\Bbb Z)^2$ where $b>1$ and $\gcd(b,n)=1$. I think it would be easy to adapt the proof to any $(b_1+n_1\Bbb Z)\times\cdots\times(b_k+n_k\Bbb Z)$ with each $\gcd(b_i,n_i)=1$ as long as we had at least two $b_i>1$.
